# Z10PE-D16 WS will not let me enter bios if PCI Nvme is installed

Tags: bios

[image]I am fighting with this thing for a couple of days. So as the title says, if my PCIe ssd is installed upon booting no keyboard is recognized and getting into bios is not possible.

I can post screen if required..

The Nvme in question is this one:

Samsung-PM1725b-Add-In-PCIe

it's where I would like to install the OS.

Are there any specific bios settings for this? I had to reset CMOs and unplug all my peripherals in order to be able to get into the bios for the first time.. Everything else ( memory, cpus ) seems to be ok. No error codes and no leds on board blinking. The Nvme is installed in the first PCIe slot ( 8x ).

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

The post error code is B7 -> Configuration reset. That is on the mobo leds.

Answer (score 0):

Issues was that this card, is not compatible with this motherboard. Simply unplugging it fixed the issue.